# AJAX- how to query a specific table row

Tags: php, ajax

I'm rather new to ajax, currently im making a task manager table which adds new rows to a table through sql queries. However I want to use ajax to change the state from 'not done' to 'done' on any tasks the users wants to finish. The problem is im not quite sure how I would go about referring to the new table rows being referenced since right now its only referencing the first instance of the rable row.

Below is my table and ajax.

```
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tasks)) : ?>

                <tr class="task-table-row" style="background-color:<?php echo $table ?>">
                    <td class="rounded" style="height:40px; overflow:hidden">
                        <?php echo $row["taskTitle"] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rounded" id="taskBodyS">
                        <?php echo $row["taskBody"]; ?></td>
                    <td class="rounded"><?php echo $row['taskDate']; ?></td>
                    <td class="state">
                        <a id="stateTick" onclick="completeTask()" method="GET"
                            action="index.php?complete_task=<?php echo $row['taskID']; ?>">Test</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="del"><a style="color:red"
                                href="index.php?del_task=<?php echo $row['taskID']; ?>">Delete
                            </a>
                            <button style="color:red; background:none; border:none; cursor:pointer">Edit
                            </button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $row['taskID']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </table>
```

```
function completeTask() {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //instance of HTTP request
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "includes/query.php", false);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  var elmt = document.getElementById("stateTick");
  elmt.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: you need to pass value through `ajax` or `<a>` ?

Comment: I assume it would be through ajax, since in order to change the state it would need to refer to a specific id. But im not quite sure how that would be possible

Answer (score 0):

You can passed the value of id in function and then send it to ajax . i.e: `<a>` tag will look like below :

```
<a id="stateTick" onclick="completeTask(<?php echo $row['taskID'];?>)">Test</a>
```

Your ajax code will look like below :

```
function completeTask(id) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //instance of HTTP request
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "includes/query.php?id="+id, false);//passing id
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  var elmt = document.getElementById("stateTick");
  elmt.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Then get this `id` using `$_GET['id']` in your php side .